# Dialog component's primefaces datatable update takes more time to load

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("gridVal");
```

when i click to open dialog component, i need to update my datatable which is inside the dialog component
but while i do, it takes more time to load(more than 5-8 secs)

Alternative solution would be appreciable.
thanks!

Comment: Please read your question as if you were an outsider. Would you be able to provide constructive help (besides telling to profile the application or get more detailed timing results?)

Comment: yes, i need to update my datatable whenever i click to open. but thread is occupying the time(more than 5-8 secs) then dialog opened. if i dont update datatable, it dont take much time.

Comment: I fail to see what your comment has to do with all I ask in my previous comment